# How to select a user from A when it has a match in B

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I have 2 tables like this:

```
TableA

+----+------- --+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Max      |
|  2 | Susan    |
|  3 | Tom      |
+----+----------+

TableB

+----+----------+----------+
| id | fromUser | toUser   |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | 3        |
|  2 | 1        | 2        |
|  3 | 3        | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Now, I want to have `Tom` as a result because `Max` gives to `Tom` and `Tom` gives to `Max`.

I know `Max's` ID.

I tried:

```
 select a.*, b.fromUser from TableA a 
 INNER JOIN TableB b 
    ON b.fromUser = a.id OR b.toUser = a.id
    WHERE b.fromUser = 1 AND a.id =! 1
```

and a lot of variations of this query. But I either got the wrong results or too many!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 1 row from `TableA` as a result, right?
You can use `EXISTS` twice:

```
select a.*
from TableA a
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from TableB 
    where fromUser = a.id and toUser = 1
  )
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from TableB 
    where fromUser = 1 and toUser = a.id
  )
```

Comment: i also tried the exists way.. but I forgot the second exists query. it works! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You need two joins to bring in the user names.  But then you also need to find users where the opposite relation exists.

So:

```
select ato.name
from tableB b join
     tableA afr
     on b.fromuser = afr.id join
     tableA ato
     on b.touser = afr.id
where exists (select 1
              from tableB b2
              where b2.fromuser = b.touser and b2.touser = b.fromuser
             ) and
      afr.name = 'Max';
```

If you know Max's id, you don't need both joins;

```
select ato.name
from tableB b join
     tableA ato
     on b.touser = afr.id
where exists (select 1
              from tableB b2
              where b2.fromuser = b.touser and b2.touser = b.fromuser
             ) and
      b.fromuser = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

use join with tablea twice

```
 select a.name as fromuser,a1.name as touser
  tableB b left join tableA a on
  b.fromUser =a.id
 left join tableA a1 on b.touser=a1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to model the graph kind of relationship in the second table, and you are clear of depth level, then you have to do self join with table as:

```
Select a.id, a.fromUser, a.toUser, b.toUser as toUser_2 
From TableB a join
     TableB b
on a.toUser = b.fromUser
and a.id < b.id
```

```
Output
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| id | fromUser | toUser   |  toUser_2|
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 1        | 3        | 1        |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```